# Systemd delay start time on boot for calendar events or wait for other services

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I'm fairly new to systemd/systemctl and I'm currently setting up a service to manage my backups. The service is persistent and scheduled to run daily. But this means the timer expires at midnight and the service will run on the first boot of the day. Usually I tend to run apt update and other things on the first boot, that often require restarts. I would rather have it start with a delay for example of half an hour after boot.

I know I can add a sleep command to my backup script, but I find this rather inelegant solution, also I start the service manually for triggering manual backups, which would be affected by the delay too.

Also I have a backup check service that should run monthly and the way it works so far would run at the same time as the daily backup service.
 Is there some way to tell a service to wait until another one is not running?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If midnight isn’t the best time for your timer to run, then choose a different time?

```
OnCalendar=16:00
```

This would run your backups at teatime each day instead of midnight.

Comment: The main area of concern is that after a boot I don't want my system to be directly slowed down by the backup and that I often will have a restart happening causing the backup to fail. I know I can change the timing but this does not really avert the issue. Especially if the laptop was off and missed a start time.